# Can't load third-party module mean.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bower, mean-stack

js..

Im trying to load a third-party module, smart-table

> http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

bower install angular-smart-table

But when i add 'smart-table' to my var

> applicationModuleVendorDependencies

in

> /public/config.js

my site dosen't load, the only thing i get is a white page ?
And when remove 'smart-table' its load normally again

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: yes, it dosen't return any errors.

Comment: check if your library is getting downloaded in resource tab.

Comment: it loads everything except, smart-table and the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add references to script files to **config\env\all.js**, like:

```
assets: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'               
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js',
                'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
                'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
```